# opinions needed for saving data

Tags: ios, core-data, nscoder

I'm creating an app that needs to save arrays. For test purposes I'm currently using a property list file. I was looking at the other methods of storing long term data. Core data and NSCoder seems promising.

I`m saving very simple pieces of data, mostly arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

and

```
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
```

see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite. Create a table named arrays, and each row should be the serialized version of the array. You can probably use something like SBJson for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out lectures 12, 13, and 14 in "iPad and iPhone Application Development", free on iTunes U. These are from Stanford University, taught by Prof. Paul Hegarty, and are really solid. There is a full demo along with the lectures and he covers plenty to get you setup.

They also have a course site online:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

But be sure to check out the lectures - he covers a LOT more than is in the slides.

I would recommend going ahead and learning Core Data - it is a bit more up front but is scalable. Also, it works with iCloud quite easily, so if you eventually want iCloud support you'll definitely want to use CD.

Good luck,

Damien